# Google SpreadSheet Api and Plus Sign In - Android App

Tags: android, google-api, google-sheets, google-plus, google-drive-api

Following the Google Sheets Api examples, I wish to allow the user of my android application to authenticate with his google user account, access a spreadsheet in his google drive account and extract the cell content. So far I have managed to succesfully login with the Google+ Sign in button and have a working GoogleApiClient. From here on it seems unclear how to proceed to use this authentication to authorize the SpreadSheetService to obtain the necessary Sheets feeds. Authorizing with hard coded credentials as in

```
service.setUserCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

works and allows me to continue to access the feeds, but is it not possible to use the GoogleApiClient authentication for authorization of this service? Or is there another way to obtain these credentials (i.e. Drive.Query)?